# Open URL on Ios in Safari?

Tags: c++, ios, url, safari

I'm using C++ Builder for Application programming. I want to know how to open an URL on an Ios Device in Safari ( simply on an button click ) . Would be nice if anyone has an answer to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]];
```

For further details Check [UIApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer . But how do i implement the UiApplication in C++ Builder ?

Comment: Do a bit googling u would find, or u could use Qt as well :)

Comment: I cant find anything about that just in c# delphi etc but not how to implement in c++ Builder . Do you know how it might work ?